# Stack Linked list based implementaion in C++

Tags: c++, stack

This is my second implementation of the Stack in c++. I already implemented it as an array-based [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278376/stack-array-based-implementation-in-c)

I need a review for it to improve it and improve my coding skill. I also will but this implementation on my GitHub account

```
//======================================================
// Author      : Omar_Hafez
// Created     : 27 July 2022 (Wednesday)  11:02:46 AM
//======================================================

#include <iostream>

enum InsertStatus { FailedStackEmpty = -1, FailedStackFull = -2, OK = 0 };

template <class T>
class Stack {
   private:
    int size = 0;

   public:
    struct Node {
        T value;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };

    Node* top;

    Stack() { top = nullptr; }

    Stack(int MAX_SIZE) {
        //  this constructor is to keep the consistency with the array based implementation
        top = nullptr;
    }

    bool isEmpty() { return !top; }

    bool isFull() { return 0; }

    int getSize() const { return size; }

    InsertStatus push(T const& t) {
        Node* node = new Node;
        node->value = t;
        node->next = top;
        top = node;
        size++;
        return OK;
    }

    InsertStatus pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) return FailedStackEmpty;
        Node* tmp_ptr = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete tmp_ptr;
        size--;
        return OK;
    }

    T stackTop() { return top->value; }

    void clearStack() {
        for (Node* tmp_ptr; top; tmp_ptr = top) {
            top = top->next;
            delete tmp_ptr;
        }
        size = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you use new and delete and not smart pointers?

Comment: @infinitezero I think that the smart pointers are not needed in this small simple code. I think the smart pointer will be better in complicated applications.

Comment: @Omar_Hafez It is best to teach yourself to *always* use smart pointers where possible, regardless of the size of the project.. As infinitezero showed in his review, even in "this small simple code", your use of manual `new` and `delete` has caused a bug.

Answer (score 3):

## Method Names

`T stackTop()` and `void clearStack` should not contain the word `stack`, because they already operate on a class called `Stack`.

## Use const for methods where appropriate

As pointed out in the last code review, you should mark methods as `const` that do not modify your object. You did this for `getSize()`, but forgot this for `stackTop()`, `isEmpty()` and `isFull()`.

## Don't expose implementation details

There is no need that `struct Node` is accessible from outside the class (i.e. `public`). It is only needed within your stack, so it should be `private`. Same goes for the `top` attribute. If `top` is public, I could manipulate it from the outside and could invalidate your entire stack. You don't want that!

Currently I can do this:

```
Stack<int> stack;
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.top = nullptr;
```

## Test your code!

If you run this code, you'll notice your clear function does not behave as expected, you'll get

> double free or corruption (out)

This is a serious bug!

## Use the right loop

There are different loops available. While (no pun intended!) you can pretty much use any loop to do anything, some loops are better suited for a job than others.

You should use a for loop, when you iterate from one point to another. For example from beginning to end or from 1 to `n`.

```
for(Node* tmp_ptr; top; tmp_ptr = top){
    top = top->next;
    delete tmp_ptr;
}
```

This should be a while loop, because you're effectively running it **while** top is not pointing to null.

Also, this is the source of your bug, because you try to delete an unitialised tmp_ptr.

You already wrote functions to delete an element and to check if the stack is  empty. Use them! It is now very elegant to clear your stack.

```
while( !isEmpty() ){
    pop();
}
```

## Use auto

When it is possible to deduce the type, you should use auto. This will allow you to change your code more easily without having to change all the respective types. There are other parts in your code where this is possible.

```
InsertStatus push(T const& t) {
    //Node* node = new Node; OLD
    auto* node = new Node;
    node->value = t;
    node->next = top;
    top = node;
    size++;
    return OK;
}
```

Also, consider using a constructor for your `Node`, so you can do `new Node(t, top);`

## isFull / max_size

Currently this method is useless and always returns false.

You can supply your constructor with a default value. Then you do not need to declare two constructors. Also you can use the initilization list

```
Stack(int MAX_SIZE = 10000) 
: top(nullptr)
, max_size(MAX_SIZE)
{
}
```

You should of course implement a `max_size` attribute. If you do not implement int, remove the MAX_SIZE alltogether, because it's doing nothing at the moment (it's not even saved).

## Finally

As discussed in the last example, use smart pointers. You said, it's a small example and not needed, but the fact that you programmed [a serious bug](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/double-free-or-corruption-cpp/) is evidence enough for me, to use smart pointers even in this small example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great review and effort. I see It was a misunderstanding from me for the smart pointers. I will use it even with small simple codes:) (Actually, when the pointer is used in the code I shouldn't say that this is a simple code anyway :) ).

Answer (score 2):

The following are in addition to [infinitezero's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278403/56343):

#### Add some logic to your `Node` class.

In C++, a `struct` and a `class` are nearly identical concepts with the sole difference being whether members are `private` or `public` by default. So, you can add methods to a `struct`. A constructor for your `Node` class would simplify some of your `Stack` methods.

```cpp
class Node
{
    Node(T the_value, Node* the_next)
    {
        value = the_value;
        next = the_next;
    }
}
```

Now, `Stack::push(T value)` can be simplified to this:

```cpp
InsertStatus Stack::push(T value)
{
    top = new Node(value, top);
    ++size;
    return OK;
}
```

#### Additional benefits of smart pointers

Let's say that both `Stack::top` and `Node::next` were represented by a `std::unique_ptr<T>`. How does `Stack::pop()` change?

```cpp
InsertStatus pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) return FailedStackEmpty;
    top = std::move(top->next);
    size--;
    return OK;
}
```

There's a bunch of machinery under the hood of `std::unique_ptr`, but that one line does the correct actions: sets `top` to the second item in the stack and deletes the original top item.

#### `Stack` needs a destructor

When a `Stack` instance goes out of scope, none of the items in the `Stack` are deleted. The memory for those items will be uselessly used up until the program quits. This is a memory leak and needs to be fixed. Luckily, the fix is simple: create a destructor.

```cpp
~Stack()
{
    clearStack();
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the destructor. Of course, this would also be a non-issue if smart-pointers were used :)

Comment: @infinitezero I think a destructor is still needed. Letting the smart pointer handle the Stack destructor would lead to recursive calls to destroy each item in the Stack (delete top calls delete top->next which calls delete top->next->next which ... etc.). If the Stack is too deep, then the program will crash with a stack overflow.

Comment: @MarkH +1 for the destructor. This is my first time noticing this important topic. Thanks a lot